# How to specify multiple entries in TERM environment variable?

Tags: ncurses, ansi-escape, terminfo

Reading through http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html it sounds as if it should be possible to assign multiple entries (e.g. "ansi+erase" and "ansi+cup") to the TERM environment variable.

1. Is it possible to specify multiple entries?
2. How are entries separated (e.g. spaces, commas)?

Comment: No. The standard procedure used to be : clone an existing terminal type and give it a new name + add a capability. Newer versions of termcap allowd you to refer to the older entry, but you still had to introduce a new terminal-type-name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A terminfo entry is *compiled*, making an entry in the terminal database.  The entries mentioned ([`ansi+erase`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-ansi_erase) and [`ansi+cup`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-ansi_cup)) are convenient *building-blocks* which can be combined along with miscellaneous capabilities to make a terminfo entry.  About ten percent of the entries in the terminal database are building blocks.

Once *compiled*, you cannot modify an entry unless you make changes to the *source* and *recompile* it.  Usually one modifies an entry by

- dumping it to a source file using `infocmp`,
- editing the source file, and
- recompiling using `tic`

When modifying an entry, you could reuse the same name, or change the name.  Of course, if you reused the same name, your changes would be lost the next time the terminal database was reinstalled (or recompiled).